# How to use C++ String Streams to append int?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

could anyone tell me or point me to a simple example of how to append an int to a stringstream containing the word "Something" (or any word)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "Something" << 42;
```

For future reference, check this out.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something on this general order:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {      
    std::stringstream stream("Something ");

    stream.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    stream << 12345;

    std::cout << stream.str();
    return 0;
}
```

With a normal stream, to add to the end, you'd open with `std::ios::ate` or `std::ios::app` as the second parameter, but with string streams, that doesn't seem to work dependably (at least with real compilers -- neither gcc nor VC++ produces the output I'd expect when/if I do so).

Comment: @hassan: no, stringstream has no c_str() method

Comment: -1 The output produced is `12345hing`, as the initialization of a `std::stringstream` object without setting the position at which to start writing will cause any input to be written at the beginning of the stream buffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using boost, it has [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm) that can be be used for this.  It is basically a packaged version of the above, that works on any type that can be written to and read from a stream.

```
string s("something");

s += boost::lexical_cast<string>(12);
```

Its probably not worth using if you aren't using boost already, but if you are it can make your code clearer, especially doing something like

```
foo(string("something")+boost::lexical_cast<string>(12));
```