# using iterator to concatenate elements in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

```
string s1 = "bob"; 
string s2 = "hey";
string s3 = "joe";
string s4 = "doe";

vector<string> myVec;

myVec.push_back(s1);
myVec.push_back(s2);
myVec.push_back(s3);
myVec.push_back(s4);
```

How do I output "bob hey" "bob hey joe" "bob hey joe doe" using an iterator on myVec?

Any help hints or help would be appreciated

Comment: What output exactly do you expect? What type will the output values have: string or integer?

Comment: the output will be in strings. thanks seeing the mistake

Comment: Define _certain elements_ criterion ? Is it in order `1 12 123 1234 12345 ... 123456789` ?

Comment: Are you having trouble coming up with an algorithm, or is C++ giving you problems?

Comment: The numbers were a bad example. I have edited to make it more clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
for (auto it = myVec.begin(), end = myVec.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    for (auto it2 = myVec.begin(); it2 != (it + 1); ++it2)
    {  
        std::cout << *it2 << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
bob 
bob hey 
bob hey joe 
bob hey joe doe
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34228649bd55864b)

Answer (score 2):

```
using namespace std;

auto it_first = begin(myVec);
auto it_last = begin(myVec) + 2;
while (it_last != end(myVec)) 
    for_each(it_first, it_last++, [](string const & str) { cout << str << " "; });
    cout << endl;
}
```

This should do it. EDIT: Corrected bug :) that should give you the correct output please confirm. There was an extra next.

Comment: Why `next`? I think he wants to include the first element. Also, this might fail if the vector contains less than 2 elements.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, if you can use `boost`:

```
 std::vector<std::string> s { "bob", "hey", "joe", "doe" };
 std::vector<std::string> d;

 for (auto i = std::begin(s); i != std::end(s); ++i) {
     d.push_back(boost::algorithm::join(
         boost::make_iterator_range(std::begin(s), i + 1), 
         std::string(" ")
     ));
 }
```

The output vector `d` will contain the following:

```
bob
bob hey
bob hey joe
bob hey joe doe
```

But more efficient solution is using temporary string:

```
 std::vector<std::string> s { "bob", "hey", "joe", "doe" };
 std::vector<std::string> d;

 std::string t;
 std::for_each(std::begin(s), std::end(s), [&](const std::string &i) {
     d.push_back(t += (i + " "));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a stringstream the exact same way as cout.  Rather than printing to the screen, they will be saved in a string.  The string can be accessed with .str().

See this: [How to use C++ String Streams to append int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066184/how-to-use-c-string-streams-to-append-int)

Your code would look something like this:

```
vector <int> myVec;
std::stringstream ss;

for(int i=0; i<10; i++)  
    myVec.push_back(i);  //vector holding 0-9

vector<int>::iterator it;
for(it=myVec.begin(); it!=myVec.end(); ++it) {
    ss<<*it<<endl;
    cout << ss.str() << " ";   // prints 1 12 123 1234 ...
}

// ss.str() == "123456789";
```

Comment: I think he wanted to print something like `1 12 123 ...`

Comment: `for(it=myVec.begin(); it!=myVec.end(); ++it) {
    ss<<*it<<endl; 
    cout << ss.str():
}`

Comment: Cool, looks like I didn't understand the problem :p

Answer (score 1):

You can try to concatinate as below using `std::string` `+ operator` and `iterator`

```
std::string myCompleteString;
vector<std::string>::iterator it;
for(it=myVec.begin(); it!=myVec.end(); ++it)
        myCompleteString  += *it +  " ";

cout << myCompleteString;
```

Comment: I'd prefer `stringstream` instead of repeated string concatenation, but I guess performance doesn't really matter in this case.

Comment: @Excelcius yes right. Also, OPs original question was related to concatenation of strings ;)